# How to obtain SIDs of Sql Server installed NT Service Accounts

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, security

I am using WMI to obtain members of server local groups, as well as the SIDs of the members. The WQL queries work for members that are local users, local groups, AD domain users and AD domain groups. However when the script is looking at members that happen to be SQL Server related, it cannot find the object in the class it thinks it should look at, and therefore I don't get the SID of the members. For example, here are some queries constructed dynamically for group members that happen to be SQL Server related:

```
select SID from Win32_SystemAccount where Domain='NT SERVICE' and Name='SQLBrowser'
select SID from Win32_SystemAccount where Domain='NT SERVICE' and Name='MsDtsServer100'
select SID from Win32_SystemAccount where Domain='NT SERVICE' and Name='SQLAgent$SQLEXPRESS'
select SID from Win32_SystemAccount where Domain='NT SERVICE' and Name='MSSQL$EPROVISIONAPP'
select SID from Win32_SystemAccount where Domain='NT SERVICE' and Name='MSOLAP$EPROVISIONAPP'
select SID from Win32_SystemAccount where Domain='NT SERVICE' and Name='ReportServer$EPROVISIONAPP'
select SID from Win32_SystemAccount where Domain='NT SERVICE' and Name='SQLAgent$EPROVISIONAPP'
```

The queries above do not return any result, even though the PartComponent of such members tells me that the member is from the Win32_SystemAccount class, and the Domain is 'NT Service'.

On the server, if I look at Local Users and Groups -> Groups, and look at the properties of a group, say "SQLServerSqlAgentUser$myservername$SQLEXPRESS", it has one member "NT SERVICE\SQLAgent$SQLEXPRESS (S-1-5-80-592940576-165...". I cannot see the entire value of the SID.

I cannot figure out how Microsoft is pulling the SID of such members, where it is getting them from.

Any ideas?

Comment: the short answer to your question is "from the system list of SIDs" which should be found in the registry, at the very least. But the more important question is "why do you need the SIDs?"

Comment: We use SID as the primary key for tracking objects and memberships on local systems. For group members that are objects in some domain, we are able to obtain the objectSID attribute of the object which matches what Win Users and Groups displays.

Comment: Using D:\temp\SysinternalsSuite>psgetsid "NT SERVICE\SQLAgent$SQLEXPRESS", I am able to see the SID of the object. However, when I search the server's registry for that value, I cannot find it.

Comment: That is likely because you don't have the local server registry permissions to search for those values. Have you asked someone with domain administrative rights to look for those values for you?

Comment: I had one of our domain admins connect to the server with escalated privs 1) He could not find any key or value in the registry that matched the value I have him, 2) Using PowerShell Get-WmiObject he could not find SqlAgent$SQLEXPRESS in either Win32_SystemAccount or Win32_UserAccount.

Comment: that matched _what value_?

Comment: I used psgetsid "NT SERVICE\SQLAgent$SQLEXPRESS" to get the full SID value for "NT SERVICE\SQLAgent$SQLEXPRESS" which is a member of one of the local groups.  Since I could not find the SID that I found in the registry, I asked the domain admin if he could find that value in the registry, and he could not either.

Comment: D:\temp\SysinternalsSuite>psgetsid "NT SERVICE\SQLAgent$SQLEXPRESS"

PsGetSid v1.44 - Translates SIDs to names and vice versa
Copyright (C) 1999-2008 Mark Russinovich
Sysinternals - www.sysinternals.com

SID for NT SERVICE\SQLAgent$SQLEXPRESS:
S-1-5-80-592940576-1656185091-296729330-4026955537-2205062631


D:\temp\SysinternalsSuite>

Comment: Let's start over again. Why do you need the SIDs?

Comment: This is "funny" but [RTFM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143504(v=sql.105).aspx) tells: "The SQL Server Agent service is disabled on instances of SQL Server Express and SQL Server Express with Advanced Services"

Answer (score 3):

From the [WMI documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394084%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), I couldn't find any way to directly obtain a service SID, probably because as far as I've seen, service SIDs aren't physical directory objects, and thus couldn't be queried except where they appear as part of ACLs. This would also explain why the values aren't persisted in the registry.

Having said that, the service SIDs definitely do not appear in `Win32_SystemAccount`. Using PowerShell on a sample machine, you can verify this by running `Get-WmiObject -Query "SELECT * FROM Win32_SystemAccount"`.

Luckily, however, there are alternatives:

1. Per [this TechNet blog post](http://blogs.technet.com/b/voy/archive/2007/03/22/per-service-sid.aspx), the non-well-known portion of a service SID is generated by taking a SHA1 hash of the uppercase service name, and then splitting apart the results into five unsigned 4-byte numbers. The following code performs this computation and returns the SID as displayed in Windows:

   ```
   DECLARE @serviceName nvarchar(128) = 'MSSQL$SQL2008R2DEV';

   SELECT
       'S-1-5-80' +
           '-' + CONVERT(varchar(20), CONVERT(bigint, CONVERT(varbinary(4), sys.fn_varbintohexsubstring(0, a.BinSid, 17, 4), 2))) +
           '-' + CONVERT(varchar(20), CONVERT(bigint, CONVERT(varbinary(4), sys.fn_varbintohexsubstring(0, a.BinSid, 13, 4), 2))) +
           '-' + CONVERT(varchar(20), CONVERT(bigint, CONVERT(varbinary(4), sys.fn_varbintohexsubstring(0, a.BinSid, 9, 4), 2))) +
           '-' + CONVERT(varchar(20), CONVERT(bigint, CONVERT(varbinary(4), sys.fn_varbintohexsubstring(0, a.BinSid, 5, 4), 2))) +
           '-' + CONVERT(varchar(20), CONVERT(bigint, CONVERT(varbinary(4), sys.fn_varbintohexsubstring(0, a.BinSid, 1, 4), 2)))
       FROM
       (
           SELECT
               CONVERT(varbinary(20), REVERSE(HASHBYTES('SHA1', UPPER(@serviceName)))) AS BinSid
       ) a;
   ```

   The binary SID can also be obtained by using the [`SUSER_SID`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179889%28v=sql.100%29.aspx) function (with some extra processing to handle the fixed portion) in lieu of [`HASHBYTES`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174415%28v=sql.100%29.aspx). (Note that the raw binary SID must have its endianness reversed before conversion and output. Also, the `@serviceName` variable being **n**varchar is important.)

   If you have .NET available, doing the hash calculation is trivial. Here's the C# code to do it:

   ```
   using System.Security.Cryptography;

   ...

   string serviceName = "MSSQL$SQL2008R2DEV";

   HashAlgorithm ha = HashAlgorithm.Create("SHA1");
   byte[] hash = ha.ComputeHash(serviceName.ToUpper().SelectMany(c => BitConverter.GetBytes(c)).ToArray());

   string sid = "S-1-5-80";

   for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
       sid += "-" + BitConverter.ToUInt32(hash, i * 4);
   ```
2. I suspect the SIDs could be found using classes in the .NET [`System.DirectoryServices`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9t2667d1.aspx) namespace, either by inspecting group membership (fragile), or by some other method. Unfortunately, the methods I tested to directly translate a principal name into a SID failed, so I'm not sure how SQL Server does it (PInvoke?). In any event, computing the hash isn't a big deal if .NET is available (in fairness, the code will be longer without the use of LINQ).
3. Capture the relevant part of the output of the `sc` utility as used below, or run this manually if you don't care about being able to automate the solution:

   ```
   sc showsid MSSQL$SQL2008R2DEV
   ```

Answer (score 0):

This will not give you the SID, but you at least get the windows account name running the services.

```
DECLARE @engine varchar(100), @agent varchar(100)

EXECUTE master.dbo.xp_instance_regread N'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE',N'SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\MSSQLSERVER',N'ObjectName',@engine OUTPUT,N'no_output'
EXECUTE master.dbo.xp_instance_regread N'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE',N'SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\SQLSERVERAGENT',N'ObjectName',@agent OUTPUT,N'no_output'
SELECT serverproperty('ServerName'),@engine as EngineServiceAccount,@agent as AgentServiceAccount
```